# Find largest item in an array - floating point - ASM

Tags: c, assembly, asmx

I wrote this program for Integers. Here's the code for that version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int N;     // length of list
int *nums; // the list
int max;   // the result

int main( void )
{
    int i;
    printf("How large will the list be?  ");
    scanf_s("%d",&N);
    nums = (int*) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter next number:  ");
        scanf_s("%d",&(nums[i]));
    }

   __asm
   {
       mov eax, N;    // A has the count
       dec eax;       // A is end of list
       mov ebx, nums; // B is head of list
       mov ecx, 0;    // C has the current largest

top:
       cmp eax, 0; 
       jl done;

       mov edx, [ebx+eax*4];
       cmp edx, ecx;
       jg Change;
       jmp Increment;

Increment:
       //mov eax,[ebx+ecx*4];
       dec eax; 
       jmp top;

Change:
       mov ecx, edx;
       jmp Increment;
done:
       mov max, ecx;
   }
   printf("Largest number in list = %d\n",max);
   scanf_s("%d",i);

}
```

Now, I need to do the same for floating point numbers. For the most part, I know I can't use the same registers to store things, and I know I have to use "fcomi" instead of "cmp". I have pored over it for hours, but really need some guidance. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int N;       // length of list
float *nums; // the list
float max;   // the result

int main( void )
{
    int i;
    printf("How large will the list be?  ");
    scanf_s("%d",&N);
    nums = (float*) malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter next number:  ");
        scanf_s("%f",&(nums[i]));
    }

    __asm
    {
        mov eax, N;     // A has the count
        dec eax;        // A is end of list
        mov esi, nums;  // B is head of list
        mov ecx, 0;     // C has the current largest

        cmp eax, 0;     // Check to see if counter has finished
        jl done;        // Jump to end
top:
        fld [esi+eax*4];    // Load first item to compare
        dec eax;            // Decrement counter
        fld [esi+eax*4];    // Load second item to compare
        fcomi st(0), st(1); // Compare the two items
        ja Change;          // Jump if st0 is above st1

        fstp max;           // Store in max, then pop from stack
        jmp Increment;      // Jump to Increment

Increment:
        dec eax;            // Decrement counter 
        jmp top;            // Jump to top

Change:
        fstp max;
        jmp Increment;
done:
    }
    printf("Largest number in list = %d\n",max);
    scanf_s("%d",i);

}
```

I've programmed mainly in C++ and have done assembly in MIPS, but both C and the embedded ASM is extremely new to me. Any help is appreciated!

-Rachel

Comment: if you're on any modern x86 machine you can just use the SSE registers which are easier to deal with